# accessing public folder in laravel using blade

Tags: css, laravel-5, laravel-blade

I have a view called `homePage.blade.php` which is my master page which resides in `res/views/` in that file I have this.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/coreStyleSheet.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/animate.css">
<script src="js/coreScripting.js"></script>
<script src="js/moments.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="icons/fontAwesome/css/font-awesome.css"> </head>
```

all is fine?

Now I create a folder called `AppCreate` who's path is `res/views/AppCreate` I have a blade file there called `something.blade.php` now when I use `@extends('homePage')` I am not able to access the css,js.

my tree looks like this.

-res
  -views
     homePage.blade.php
     -AppCreate
       -something.blade.php

I redirect something.blade.php tp public/admin/appcreate
I redirect homePage.blade.php to public/dashBoard.

I hope I have explained it well.

when I access the public /admin/appcreate laravel is not able to find the css and the js because it says this.

```
    GET http://localhost/laravel/public/admin/css/coreStyleSheet.css 
appcreate:12 GET http://localhost/laravel/public/admin/js/moments.js 
appcreate:11 GET http://localhost/laravel/public/admin/js/coreScripting.js 
appcreate:13 GET http://localhost/laravel/public/admin/icons/fontAwesome/css/font-awesome.css
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Try using the [Helper Functions](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/helpers) like this:

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('css/animate.css') }}">`

`<script src="{{ asset('js/coreScripting.js') }}"></script>`

assuming you have your **css** and **js** folders inside **public/assets**

Comment: saved the day. Thanks bud :)

Comment: @sodji not working for me