# did not work jquery codes in Laravel 5.6 app

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css, laravel-5

working with Laravel 5.6 and I have following form load with open when click the button,

```
<button class="open-button" onclick="openForm()">Open Form</button>

<div class="form-popup" id="myForm">
  <form action="/action_page.php" class="form-container">
    <h1>Login</h1>

    <label for="email"><b>Email</b></label>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Email" name="email" required>

    <label for="psw"><b>Password</b></label>
    <input type="password" placeholder="Enter Password" name="psw" required>

    <button type="submit" class="btn">Login</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn cancel" onclick="closeForm()">Close</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

and following script codes to load file,

```
<script>
function openForm() {
    document.getElementById("myForm").style.display = "block";
}

function closeForm() {
    document.getElementById("myForm").style.display = "none";
}
</script>
```

and following css,

```
<style>
body {font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;}
* {box-sizing: border-box;}

/* Button used to open the contact form - fixed at the bottom of the page */
.open-button {
  background-color: #555;
  color: white;
  padding: 16px 20px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  opacity: 0.8;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 23px;
  right: 28px;
  width: 280px;
}

/* The popup form - hidden by default */
.form-popup {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 15px;
  border: 3px solid #f1f1f1;
  z-index: 9;
}
<style>
```

I have load css file with external css file like this,

```
<link href="{{ asset('css/report.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
```

and external file js as,

```
<script src="{{ url('/js/report.js') }}"></script>
```

my css file is loading but js file is not working, how can fix this problem?

Comment: Why are your css styles wrapped with a <style> tag and your javascript code with a <script> tag if you're using css/js files? Maybe this causes the error. And "not working" doesn't help. What is the error output of the console?

Comment: I removed them but still problem here

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
<script src="{{ asset('js/report.js') }}"></script>
```

Remove the forward slash at starting and use helper asset if js directory is in public folder

Comment: what is the location of your js file in project?

Answer (score 0):

Change your path to

```
<link href="{{ public_path('css/report.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
```

and

```
<script src="{{ public_path('js/report.js') }}"></script>
```

If you're using the helper function `assets` your files should be stored in public/assets. Otherwise you should take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42142042/accessing-public-folder-in-laravel-using-blade) answer.

It should also help to take a look at your source code what the exact URL's are to your css & js files and if the paths are correct.

Comment: actuaaly I thing your codes also not working in my side. that means my js codes are not in correct place. can you put this in correct place in Laravel?

Comment: Where are your files located? Are you using Laravel elixir to compile assets?

Comment: my css and js files are located in public folder

Comment: I wrote several solutions. "is is not work for me" doesn't help. Read the answer and try those things. Check the path of the files in your source code of the site.